# SAPUI5 root view

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a problem with rootview. I want create 2 views (login form and home with navigation list).

this is my home view:

[image: Home View]

I want when I clicked menu in left (root item 1, 2, etc), show content form (just content and still showing menu). I success when root view set to home view but in login view have menu component (navigation list). I want set root view to Home when i load home view, and set root view to other (exclude Home view) when i load login view.

Component.js :

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
], function (UIComponent) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("sap.ui.demo.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        }, 

        createContent : function() {
            // create root view
            var oView = sap.ui.view({
                id : "mainContents",
                viewName : "sap.ui.demo.template.App",
                type : "XML", // <-- change this to JSON
                viewData : {
                    component : this
                }
            });

            // done
            return oView;
        },  

        init: function () {
            // call the init function of the parent
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);  // calling parent UIComponents

            // create the views based on the url/hash
            this.getRouter().initialize();                      // initializing router
//            this.i18nModel();                                 // set i18n model
        },

        i18nModel : function(){
            var i18nModel = new ResourceModel({
                bundleName: "sap.ui.demo.template.i18n.i18n"
            });
            this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");               
        }

    });

});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "_version": "1.1.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "id": "sap.ui.demo.template",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "applicationVersion": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "technology": "UI5",
    "deviceTypes": {
      "desktop": true,
      "tablet": true,
      "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": [
      "sap_hcb",
      "sap_bluecrystal",
      "sap_belize"
    ]
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "rootView": 
        {
          "viewName": "sap.ui.demo.template.Home",
          "type": "XML",
          "id": "app"
        }
    ,
    "dependencies" : {
      "minUI5Version": "1.30",
      "libs": {
        "sap.ui.core": {},
        "sap.m": {},
        "sap.tnt": {},
        "sap.ui.layout": {}
      }
    },
    "models": {
      "i18n": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
        "settings": {
          "bundleName": "sap.ui.demo.template.i18n.i18n"
        }
      }
    },
    "routing": {
      "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "controlId": "mainContents",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "controlAggregation": "pages",
        "viewPath": "sap.ui.demo.template",
        "async": true
      },
      "routes": [
        {
          "pattern": "",
          "name": "first",
          "target": "first"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "home",
          "name": "home",
          "target": "second"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "page1",
          "name": "page1",
          "target": "page1"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "login",
          "name": "login",
          "target": "login"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "mainContents",
          "name": "mainContents",
          "target": "mainContents"
        }
      ],
      "targets": {
        "first": {
          "viewName": "Index"
        },
        "second": {
          "viewName": "Home"
        },
        "page1": {
          "viewName": "Page1"
        },
        "login": {
          "viewName": "Index"
        },
        "mainContents": {
          "viewName": "Home"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I if set root view to Home :

[image: Login false]

I want to this:

[image: login true]

when I set rootview to App, login true but home view false.

App view:

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="false">

    <App id="mainContents" class="blueBackground">
    </App>

</mvc:View>
```

How to fix this problem about rootview?

Thanks. Bobby.

Answer (score 0):

Set rootview to one view, Handle the rest of the view traversals in controller, with router.navTo() function where you can specify pattern as well.
Just do a cleanup while navigating to another view, destroy the menu created. and create it again on traversal to the concerned view